# How to Implement OAuth correctly in API with Laravel Passport?

Tags: php, laravel, api, oauth, laravel-passport

I'm trying to create an *API* and use it in my own applications (web application and native mobile app) and make it available for third-party applications ( this is for future purposes).

I've read the [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport) documentation, and I have some doubts that hopefully someone could help me with it.

As a developer, I always try to find the best and correct way to implement my projects and find the appropriate packages for the purposes of the projects.

---

**Brief explanation of what I want to do:**

I want to create an *API* and I will consume my own *API* in my web and mobile applications, my *API* has two endpoints for register and login for **students** and **teachers**. They can login with their email and password. Each user type has its own information. A teacher can have a **CV**, and students can see teachers' CV( the whole creating and reading **CV's** are handling in my API ), and they both user types can communicate with each other. I'm using **laravel 6.x** version to build my *API*. We have a section for developers in our subdomain which **developers** can register accounts and get/buy an **access token** to make requests to my API and use it, on the other hand, I want when students or teachers login to their accounts the *API* generates an **access token** for that user so then my application can use that token and pass that in every requests to make users be authenticated to access their private resources like their Dashboard as we know *API's* are stateless and we can't use sessions to store user credentials, so we need an access token for that.

> Can **Laravel Passport** generate the both **Developer access token**, and **User( teacher or student) access token**?
> Is it correct to use **OAuth** in here to develop my *API*?
> Or can I just use **tymondesigns/JWT** package for these purposes?

---

I have to say that I'm new to **Oauth** and **API based applications**. I've read some articles about **Oauth**, and I'm a little bit familiar with **Oauth terminology**, but still, I don't know how to implement this project correctly.

So here are my questions:

> 1. What is exactly **Oauth server**? Is it my own server that is hosted by *API*?

> 2. After **Laravel Passport** configuration and database migration, **Laravel Passport** created some tables in my database, I would be really appreciated if you could tell me what is the purpose of each tables? table names are **failed_jobs**, **oauth_access_tokens**, **oauth_auth_codes**, **oauth_clients**,    **oauth_personal_access_clients**, **oauth_refresh_tokens**.

> 3. I've configured my **Laravel** application to use the **Laravel Passport** and I created two **Routes** in my **api.php** file

```
Route::post('login','API\Auth\UserAuthController@login');
Route::post('register','API\Auth\UserAuthController@register');
```

and then, I created the `UserAuthController.php` file and wrote the login and register methods. They are working without any problem. After a user registers or login into their account, my code will generate a **personal access token**.

```
$token = $user->createToken('authentication')->accessToken;
```

and then students or teachers can access to the private resources of their own with this **access token**. Is it right to create a **personal access token** for my two types of users? What is exactly a **personal access token**?
I just know you can pass it into request header, and the server will authorize you to access private resources. what I mean by private resources is the endpoints which are protected by **API middleware** like this:

```
Route::post('/update-info','API\Auth\UserAuthController@update')->middleware('auth:api');
```

> 4. Am I doing right to create a **personal access token** when teachers and students login to their account or I should do another way to handle it?! this way works, but I'm looking for correct way if there is anything else.

> 5. The weird thing here is **Laravel Passport** create a token every time users login and it doesn't check if they have already created token or not? If someone can access the `API` endpoint, they can make a post request to /login endpoint and create a lot of tokens. Is it a problem? How to fix it?

> 6. When I create a **personal access token** I need to pass an argument to `createToken($arg)` method, and it stores in **oauth_personal_access_clients** table. what is the purpose of this? Is it just for **Laravel Passport** purpose, or maybe I need it in the future?

> 7. I have some endpoints which are not protected by `auth:api` **middleware**, for example, every user visit my application they can search for teachers name and lessons and ... , it's not necessary to make them login or register first. These endpoints are accessible to everyone in my application, and they are free to search and advance search for some information. My question is if I make it accessible to everyone, how can I **protect** these endpoints that **only** my **first-party app** and **third-party app** can access them. I mean I don't want people to access them by **command line** or **postman** or some kind of these tools without access token, I want to protect these endpoints from attackers not to make a huge requests to make my server down. How can I protect this kind of endpoints? I know I can **limit requests** per minute, but I don't know **how much** limit it? Is there any other way?

> 8. I see there is a term called **clients** in **Oauth terminology**, as I understand **clients** are the applications like **web applications** or **native mobile app** and any other applications that use my API are called **clients**. Am I right? And I think this is for third-party application **authentication**. I'm a little bit confused after reading **Laravel Passport** documentation about **clients**, and when I configured the **Laravel Passport**, it generates **two clients** and stored them in database. Do I need to create a client for my Applications?! How Can I ignore authorization flow **just** for first-party applications?

---

> 9. After **Laravel Passport** configuration, now I can see it generates some default route for clients.

```
/oauth/clients
/oauth/clients/{client-id}
/oauth/authorize
/oauth/token
```

What is the usage of these **routes**?! do I need them to create my **first-party applications**?

---

> 10. As I said the future purpose of this application is to make the API accessible by **third-party applications**, I have to create a web page that **developers** register an account and get/buy a **token** to access my API. is it possible to do it with **Laravel Passport** or I should write my own logic to make it work? Do I need to create a client for my third-party clients?

Thanks a lot for your help <3

Comment: Wow long question. Befor I will read this - did You checked new Laravel Sanctum? It is good for many use cases, third party apps as well (api keys). Simple and convenient, opposite to oauth ;)

Comment: @chojnicki thank you for your help , unfortunately it is a long question sorry about to hear that. No I haven't checked it , I will definitely check it and let you know, thanks <3

Comment: @chojnicki unfortunately Laravel Sanctum is not supported by Laravel 6.x version which I chose to use in my project.

Comment: Hi, without answering everyone of your questions have you considered using KeyCloak ?

Comment: @SebNik Hello, I'm still trying to read some articles to get the answer of my questions and I haven't used KeyCloak. I will definitely check it and if I find it useful for the purposes of my application I will let you know. Thank you.

Comment: Yes because once you understand what KeyCloak is most of your questions are going to be clear, because KeyCloak is a server which can preform OAutch, which is just a protocol. And KeyCloak is also a Server typically deployed on Docker or kubernetes

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's going to take too long for me to answer each of your questions in depth, so I've
tried to link to the relevant sections in the RFC for further reading.

Essentially, I would recommend for you to use the [password credentials grant flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) for your first-party clients (your mobile app and web app). One of the clients that
Laravel would have created for you, would have been the "Laravel Password Grant Client" and its
documentation is available [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#password-grant-tokens).

You would still need to define your own "register" route, but you can use the `oauth/token` route
instead of your own `/login` route.

> 1. What is exactly **Oauth server**? Is it my own server that is hosted by *API*?

The OAuth server would be your server that is running Passport. Or in the official
terminology according to the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.1), the
OAuth server/Passport server would be called the "authorization server."

In your case, the "resource server", which your API that serves your content, would be
the same server as the "authorization server."

> 2. After **Laravel Passport** configuration and database migration, **Laravel Passport** created some tables in my database, I would be really appreciated if you could tell me what is the purpose of each tables? table names are **failed_jobs**, **oauth_access_tokens**, **oauth_auth_codes**, **oauth_clients**,    **oauth_personal_access_clients**, **oauth_refresh_tokens**.

The `failed_jobs` table is not directly related to Passport. It's related to Laravel's queues. See [Dealing With Failed Jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs).

The rest of the tables are all there so that Passport can keep track of the clients and codes it has created.

- `oauth_clients`: See the [RFC clients section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1).
- `oauth_access_tokens`: See the [RFC access tokens section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.4).
- `oauth_auth_codes`: See [Authorization Code Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1).
- `oauth_personal_access_clients`: Personal access clients don't seem to be part of the official specification, but it is basically a client for when a user wants to get an access token directly, instead of going through an app or website. Usually this would be a developer who wants to get an access token to be able to call API endpoints on their own account.
  The personal access clients table stores clients that were specifically created for this purpose. Usually there would
  only be one of them.
- `oauth_refresh_tokens`: See the [RFC refresh tokens section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5).

> 3. Is it right to create a personal access token for my two types of users? What is exactly a personal access token?

Every user would need to get their own access token, but not a personal access token.

Personal access tokens are just access tokens that were created specifically for users who wants to generate
and use the access token themselves. In Laravel Passport, specifically, they are access tokens
which are linked to the "Laravel Personal Access Client."

So in your case, your server would create "normal" access tokens for users and not "personal" access
tokens.

> 4. Am I doing right to create a **personal access token** when teachers and students login to their account or I should do another way to handle it?! this way works, but I'm looking for correct way if there is anything else.

See answer to question 3.

> 5. The weird thing here is **Laravel Passport** create a token every time users login and it doesn't check if they have already created token or not? If someone can access the `API` endpoint, they can make a post request to /login endpoint and create a lot of tokens. Is it a problem? How to fix it?

I don't think this is a problem. The `oauth/token` route is rate-limited. You can rate-limit it even more.

You can also listen to [events](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#events) and delete or revoke tokens
if want to limit the amount of tokens there may be for a single user.

> 6. When I create a **personal access token** I need to pass an argument to `createToken($arg)` method, and it stores in **oauth_personal_access_clients** table. what is the purpose of this? Is it just for **Laravel Passport** purpose, or maybe I need it in the future?

This table is just for Laravel Passport. It can also be of use for when you want to audit or debug something later on.

The row that you see in the `oauth_personal_access_clients` table, was created when you ran `php artisan passport:install`.

When you call `createToken`, a new row is inserted into `oauth_access_tokens`.

> 7. I have some endpoints which are not protected by `auth:api` **middleware**, for example, every user visit my application they can search for teachers name and lessons and ... , it's not necessary to make them login or register first. These endpoints are accessible to everyone in my application, and they are free to search and advance search for some information. My question is if I make it accessible to everyone, how can I **protect** these endpoints that **only** my **first-party app** and **third-party app** can access them. I mean I don't want people to access them by **command line** or **postman** or some kind of these tools without access token, I want to protect these endpoints from attackers not to make a huge requests to make my server down. How can I protect this kind of endpoints? I know I can **limit requests** per minute, but I don't know **how much** limit it? Is there any other way?

Yes, you'll have to do rate-limiting. You'll have to experiment and see what works for you.

> 8. I see there is a term called **clients** in **Oauth terminology**, as I understand **clients** are the applications like **web applications** or **native mobile app** and any other applications that use my API are called **clients**. Am I right? And I think this is for third-party application **authentication**. I'm a little bit confused after reading **Laravel Passport** documentation about **clients**, and when I configured the **Laravel Passport**, it generates **two clients** and stored them in database. Do I need to create a client for my Applications?! How Can I ignore authorization flow **just** for first-party applications?

Yes, clients are like web applications, mobile apps, etc. Usually you would have a new
client for every mobile app, web app, CLI, etc., but in addition to those apps, Laravel defines
the "Password Grant Client" and the "Personal Access Client" clients for you which have
specific purposes.

You can use the [Laravel Password Grant Client](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#password-grant-tokens) for
both of your applications since they're first-party applications.

You can ignore the authorization flow for first-party applications by using the
[`/oauth/token`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#requesting-password-grant-tokens) route that is provided for
password grant clients.

The RFC section about the password credentials flow is available [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3).

You can read more about how the RFC defines clients [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1).

> 9. What is the usage of these **routes**? do I need them to create my **first-party applications**?

Needed for first-party applications:

- `/oauth/token`

Not needed for first-party applications:

- `/oauth/clients`: this is for a third-party developer to see which clients they have created.
- `/oauth/clients/{client-id}`: for a third-party developer to update one of their clients.
- `/oauth/authorize`: this route will be called by a third-party developer to start the
  [authorization grant flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) with their client ID and secret.

You can read more about the above routes under the "JSON API" section in [Managing clients](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#managing-clients).

> 10. As I said the future purpose of this application is to make the API accessible by **third-party applications**, I have to create a web page that **developers** register an account and get/buy a **token** to access my API. is it possible to do it with **Laravel Passport** or I should write my own logic to make it work? Do I need to create a client for my third-party clients?

Laravel Passport [provides](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#frontend-quickstart) Vue components that you can use so that developers will be able to create clients. You can either use these components or you can create your own frontend and call
the [JSON API routes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#managing-personal-access-tokens) from your own frontend.

Keep in mind that OAuth was designed originally for when third-party apps needs to access things **on behalf of a user**. So instead of getting access tokens, third-party apps will get a client ID and client secret and they will need to go through one of the [authorization grant flows](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4) for each user that they want to act on behalf of.

If you're never going to have third-party apps that need to act on behalf of users, it might be worth considering other protocols like mentioned in the comments.